# Adding multiple custom order statuses in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I tried this code written below and it worked. Only issue is I need one more status added named " Verification ". Please help me out if this is something you guys can do.

```
function register_awaiting_shipment_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => 'Awaiting shipment',
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_awaiting_shipment_order_status' );
// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-awaiting-shipment'] = 'Awaiting shipment';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_awaiting_shipment_to_order_statuses' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code, will add **"Awaiting shipment"** and **"Verification"** custom order statuses and it will replace the code from your question:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_statuses_as_order_status' );
function register_custom_statuses_as_order_status() {

    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => __('Awaiting shipment'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Awaiting shipment <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );

    register_post_status( 'wc-verification', array(
        'label'                     => __('Verification'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Verification <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Verification <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_additional_custom_statuses_to_order_statuses' );
function add_additional_custom_statuses_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
    // add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-awaiting-shipment'] = __('Awaiting shipment');
            $new_order_statuses['wc-verification'] = __('Verification');
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I tried to do the same but calling 'init' hook twice using different callbacks for each order status, and it didn't work. Why?

Comment: @svelandiag You don't need to make separated functions for the same hook… Just merge the code in one function…

Comment: Thank you! One last question, these custom statuses can be referred just as `awaiting-shipment` or do I need to specifically refer to them in my code like `wc-awaiting-shipment`

Comment: if you use order methods as get_status(), has_status(), set_status() or update_status(), you will use `awaiting-shipment` … now in a WP_Query or an SQL query you will use `wc-awaiting-shipment`.